# All users can access DBC tables by default

Tags: sql, database, select, teradata

I created a test dbuser with basic rights and as I log in with it in SQL Assistant, I can select on every tables in the DBC database. I checked with other users, and they all can. I tried :

> REVOKE SELECT ON "DBC" FROM my_user;

But it didn't work. Do you know how I can modify access rights on the DBC ?

Answer (score 1):

Those access rights are probably not granted on a user lever, but to PUBLIC. If this is actually done on `DBC` (= database level) it should be revoked, because there are some security tables like `dbc.dbase` which holds the encrypted passwords.

```
REVOKE SELECT ON "DBC" FROM public;
```

End users should only have access on dbc.views.